# Center table, hide excess parts

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to center a table on a page so excess parts that would stick outside the viewport are hidden?

Example: I have a table with three columns, each 300 pixels wide. If viewed with a browser that’s 500 pixels wide, only the rightmost 100 pixels of the first column would be visible, all of column 2 (which is perfectly center on the screen), and the leftmost 100 pixels of the third column.

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td { width: 300px; }
        div { margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

The above example shows all three columns, regardless of the browser width.

Comment: Won't that left-align the table and only hide the right part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding this css to Your table:

```
table{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px; /* half of your table width */
    width: 900px;
}
```

This will make what you wish. You may also want to add

```
body{overflow-x: hidden;} /* this will prevent browser from adding bootm scroll bar to the end of your table rigth end. If this fail then try to give some width to body, ie width: 100%; */
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But upon resizing the browser, the table is no longer properly aligned. Is there another way of centering the table?

Comment: try to give a width to Your table in CSS, here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8VGqx/

Answer (score 1):

Check with including that table in a "div" and align the div to centre